# Asp.Net MVC 5 and Hottowel 2.01/Breeze - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, ... or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, breeze, asp.net-mvc-5, hottowel

I created a new Asp.net MVC 5 project using VS 2013 and then added HotTowel 2.0.1 (http://www.nuget.org/packages/HotTowel/). The site works. However, the webapi with breeze controller get the following error when I try to get the WebApi controller of `Events`. The breeze version is 1.4.2.

The controller code is

```
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<ApplicationDbContext> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<ApplicationDbContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Event> Events()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Events;
    }
}
```

The error message is

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.IO.FileLoadException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type) at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext) at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit) at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.Initialize() at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor..ctor(HttpConfiguration configuration, String controllerName, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache() at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Comment: The latest version of breeze is 1.4.5. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your code reference system.web.http version 4.0.0.0, while your project is referencing version 5. You could either install version 4, or upgrade your code to use version 5.

If the code that refers to version 4 is in a third party lib (i.e Breeze) then you will have to get a new version from them, or install the old version (4) of the system.web.http lib.